# how can I update a list of records in a table with the new value depending on the old value

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a table called acc1152 with the field accno. depending on what the value of this field is, i need to replace it with a new value. these are the values i need to update

```
old value   new value
  7007        4007
  7008        4008
  4008        7
  7009        4009
  7011        4011
  4011        ' '
  7010        4010
  4010        1
  7016        4016
  4016        1
  4506        4006
  4512        4012
```

if the record has the old value above in its accno field, that accno needs to be replaced with the new value

how do I write one query that will accomplish this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I see a set of rules, but to make sure: could you post all rules by which a number should change?

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't provide enough information.  What criteria are you using to decide the new value?

Comment: i edited it. im working off of a pre made list of edits that have to be made. the table is huge so i cant go through and manually update all the vlaues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `case` statements in an update statement as so:

```
update acc1152
set [columnName] = 
    case [columnName]
        when '7007' then '4007'
        when '7008' then '4008'
        -- etc
        when '4512' then '4012'
    else
        [columnName] end
```

Or a better way (IMO) would be to use a temp/variable table to keep track of your old/new mappings

```
declare @someTable table (oldValue varchar(50), newValue varchar(50))
insert into @someTable (oldValue, newValue)
select '7007','4007'
union all select '7008','4008'
-- etc
union all select '4512','4012'

update acc1152
set [columnName] = st.newValue
from acc1152 a
inner join @someTable st on a.[columnName] = st.oldValue
```

Comment: @samhatcher note that in my second part of the answer, and in Gordon's answer, they're doing targeted row updates by only updating rows that have a change in old -> new value.  In the case statement above technically it is updating **every** row in the table, albeit for the rows that don't have old -> new value changes, the values are just being updated back to their existing value.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work in any database (it is ANSI standard SQL):

```
update acc1152 t
    set accno = (select r.newvalue from replacements r where r.oldvalue = t. acc1152)
    where exists (select 1 from replacements where r.oldvalue = t. acc1152);
```

Depending on the database, there are other approaches.

This assumes that your replacement values are in a table, which I called `replacements`.

Comment: im using sql server. an the updates are not coming from another table. all the updates that need to be made are on the list above. but accno values repeat multiple times throughout the table